# Realm with Gson alternative to ExclusionStrategy and custom typeadapters

Tags: android, gson, realm

So, I stated using `Realm` and encountered this known [issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1127) when combining it with `Gson`. 
I started seeing some strange serialized outputs that were breaking the logic of my Rest API.

I have found that setting an `ExclusionStrategy` and writing custom serializers to each of my models will fix it. See this [link](https://gist.github.com/cmelchior/ddac8efd018123a1e53a).

But I have more than 20 models that are more likely to be changed in the future. So sticking to this workaround means that I will have to change the serializers every time I change the models and this seems to break this simplicity I thought I would have by using `Realm` and `Gson` together.

My question is: Is there another known workaround to bypass these limitation? Or It is the only choice I have?

Comment: Note that the ExclusionStrategy is only required on older versions of Realm.  If you use the latest version (2.3.1) it isn't needed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use the ExclusionStrategy, and use `realm.copyFromRealm(managedRealmObject);` before passing it to GSON.

```
    ExclusionStrategy exclusionStrategy = new ExclusionStrategy() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
            return f.getDeclaringClass().equals(RealmObject.class);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
            return false;
        }
    };

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setExclusionStrategies(exclusionStrategy)
            .create();

    String json = gson.toJson(realm.copyFromRealm(myObject));
```